# notepad++ plugin - reading all document's text

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, notepad++

I am writing a notepad++ plugin using c# template http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip/download.

Does anyone know how do I read all the current document text as I need to read all the text to string?

Does anyone know the function which reads the current document text?

Comment: I thought Notepad++ was written in C++, correct me if I am wrong. Are you going to call its unmanaged APIs from managed code and want us to help you with the code?

Comment: I am using c# template that you van find here:http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip/download

Comment: off topic: one of the topmost lines in the Readme file says "**Forget all previous versions of this package - this is a brand new approach!**" This is scary!

Comment: Do you able yo understand how I read the current document text?

Comment: Sorry I am not a big expert in Marshalling. From what I can see you would need to call some API using export calls into Notepad++ native API. It's probably a good idea to add a C++ tag here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing the Scintilla API documentation should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETTEXT

The Demo project that you linked has an example of sending the messages.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me, using the Demo C# project you find at the Notepad++ web:

```
int length = (int) Win32.SendMessage(GetCurrentScintilla(), SciMsg.SCI_GETLENGTH, 0, 0);
IntPtr ptrToText = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length+1);
Win32.SendMessage(GetCurrentScintilla(), SciMsg.SCI_GETTEXT, length, ptrToText);
string textAnsi = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrToText);
Console.WriteLine(textAnsi);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrToText);
```

1. Get the length of the text.
2. Alloc some memory for the text.
3. Using the length and the previous pointer, get the text from Notepad.
4. With Console.WriteLine you print the message or do whateve you need.
5. Free the memory you allocated previously.

Update: http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETTEXT

It's needed to alloc an extra byte for the end of line ^^